# Waiting message for an API call to finish

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I wrote a basic generic class in Swift that makes calls to URLs and deserializes the JSON that is returned from the server (or nothing if it fails and returns a status code).

Are there any standards/best practices to wrap these calls in some sort of handler so I can see when my call finishes within my view controller?

The code for the call is something like this:

```
var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: request.Url)!)
let responseObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil)
```

Ideally what I'd like to do is while my class is doing its call to the API, I wanted to change my 'login' button's text to a little spinner to show it's trying to connect. Also if there is some lag or latency and it times out, what is the time it would try? 60 seconds or something?

What should I read up on if I wanted to do something like this? Or perhaps someone could share some code? i'm a little unsure about what the best approach is.

Comment: The recommended approach is to have a completion block for your asynchronous methods. The method should invoke the completion block when the process (JSON parsing in this case) is completed.

Comment: You can wrap this in an asynchronous block via [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html)

Comment: Thanks - how does GCD compare with using what's suggested on this site? http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/06/20/making-http-requests-in-swift/ Essentially using var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)